# What is the notation of a rectangle on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

What is the notation of the set of all points $(x, y$) on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x \in [a, b]$ and $y \in [c, d]$?

Comment: $[a,b]\times[c,d]$

Comment: Don't forget that there are rectangles which are not aligned with the axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Tanner answer,

$[a, b] \times [c, d]$

Answer (score 0):

This could be written as follows:
$$
\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \;|\; x\in[a,b] \wedge y\in[c,d]\}
$$

Comment: Points $(x,y)$ are members ($\in$), not subsets ($\subset$) of the plane.

Comment: I took the bold move of changing $\subset$ to $\in$ in HUK's answer. With that correction, it is a valid answer, and in some cases can be preferable to the more succint Cartesian product notation.

Comment: Of course, you are right. Thanks!